# Trying to build a regular expression to check pattern

Tags: regex

a) Start and end with a number
b) Hyphen should start and end with a number
c) Comma should start and end with a number
d) Range of number should be from 1-31

[Edit: Need this rule in the regex, thanks Ed-Heal!]
e) If a number starts with a hyphen (-), it cannot end with any other character other than a comma AND follow all rules listed above.
E.g. 2-2,1 OR 2,2-1 is valid while 1-1-1-1 is not valid

E.g.
a) 1-5,5,15-29
b) 1,28,1-31,15
c) 15,25,3 [Edit: Replaced 56 with 3, thanks for pointing it out Brian!]
d) 1-24,5-6,2-9

Tried this but it passes even if the string starts with a comma:

```
/^[0-9]*(?:-[0-9]+)*(?:,[0-9]+)*$/
```

Comment: The final number in (c) is larger than 31, is the example or the description wrong?

Comment: maybe you could just say that you have a list of things (separator ,), a thing is a range going from 1 to 31 (separator -) or a number

Comment: what is your language or regex flavor ?

Comment: The way you have worded constraint (e) would seem to rule out ,5, in your examples since it starts and ends with the same character. I'm guessing you really mean that you allow a comma-separated list of numbers or pairs of numbers with a hyphen in between.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?  This will check rules a, b and c, at least, but does not check rule d.

`/^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)*$/`

If you need to ensure that all the numbers are in the range 1-31, then the expression will get a whole lot uglier:

`/^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(-([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?(,([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(-([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?)*$/`

Note that your example c contains a number, 56, that does not fall within the range 1-31, so it will not pass the second expression.

Comment: +1 for meeting all the requirements without engaging in overkill. ;)  And it works in any flavor, which is good since the OP didn't specify one.  (Just replace `/` with `"` as indicated.)

Comment: +1. But that "ugly" expression would get _"a whole lot prettier"_ if you had written it in free-spacing mode with lots-o comments and indentation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workings

Numbers:

`0|([1-9][0-9]*)` call this expression A *Note this expression treats zero as a special case and prevents numbers starting with a zero eg 0000001234*

Number or a range:

`A|(A-A)` call this expression B (i.e `(0|([1-9][0-9]*))|((0|([1-9][0-9]*))-(0|([1-9][0-9]*)))`

Comma operator

B(,B)*

Putting this togher should do the trick and we get

`((0|([1-9][0-9]*))|((0|([1-9][0-9]*))-(0|([1-9][0-9]*))))(,((0|([1-9][0-9]*))|((0|([1-9][0-9]*))-(0|([1-9][0-9]*)))))*`

You can abbreviatge this with `\d` for `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$
```

[`DEMO`](http://rubular.com/r/8mR8TpkAk4)

Comment: although it can be done with `positive lookbehind assertion (?<= )`, but really not getting how to do it

Comment: `\d+` is too permissive. Numbers are in the range 1 to 31

Answer (score 0):

The other approaches have not restricted the allowed range of numbers. This allows 1 through 31 only, and seems simpler than some of the monstrosities people have come up with ...

```
^([12][0-9]?|3[01]?|[4-9])([-,]([12][0-9]?|3[01]?|[4-9]))*$
```

There is no check for sensible ranges; adding that would make the expression significantly more complex. In the end you might be better off with a simpler regex and implementing sanity checks in code.

Comment: Good point about the range being 1-31 (that I did not consider). But you expression allows 1-1-1-1-1

Answer (score 0):

Using the same logic in my previous answer but limiting the range

A becomes `[1-9]\d|3[01]`
B becomes `([1-9]\d|3[01])|(([1-9]\d|3[01])-([1-9]\d|3[01]))`

Overall expression

`(([12]\d|3[01])|(([12]\d|3[01])-([12]\d|3[01])))(,(([12]\d|3[01])|(([12]\d|3[01])-([12]\d|3[01]))))*`

Comment: I don't think your parenthesis are balanced.

Comment: Of course it should be mention that this regular expression does not handle ranges where the first number is larger than the second = now that would be a very compilcated expression! (Something left to the readers)

Comment: Fortunately, the OP didn't list lower-to-higher range expressions as a requirement.  However, you still aren't limiting the numbers correctly; `[1-9]\d|3[01]` matches numbers in the range 10..99, not 1..31.

Comment: @alan - You are right - It was end of my shift any the brain went off line. Will fix

Comment: @Ed Heal: What about single-digit numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following regex:

```
(?<number>[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]){0}(?<thing>\g<number>-\g<number>|\g<number>){0}^(\g<thing>,)*\g<thing>$
```

It looks awful but it isn't :) In fact the construction `(?<name>...){0}` allows us to define a named regex and to say that it doesn't match where it is defined. Thus I defined a pattern for  numbers called `number` and a pattern for what I called a thing i.e. a range or number called `thing`. Next I know that your expression is a sequence of those things, so I use the named regex `thing` to build it with the construct `\g<thing>`. It gives `(\g<thing>,)*\g<thing>`. That's easy to read and understand. If you allow whitespaces to be non significant in your regex, you could even indent it like this:

```
(?<number>[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]){0}
(?<thing>\g<number>-\g<number>|\g<number>){0}
^(\g<thing>,)*\g<thing>$/
```

I tested it with Ruby 1.9.2. Your regex engine should support named groups to allow that kind of clarity.

```
irb(main):001:0> s1 = '1-5,5,15-29'
=> "1-5,5,15-29"
irb(main):002:0> s2 = '1,28,1-31,15'
=> "1,28,1-31,15"
irb(main):003:0> s3 = '15,25,3'
=> "15,25,3"
irb(main):004:0> s4 = '1-24,5-6,2-9'
=> "1-24,5-6,2-9"
irb(main):005:0> r = /(?<number>[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]){0}(?<thing>\g<number>-\g<number>|\g<number>){0}^(\g<thing>,)*\g<thing>$/
=> /(?<number>[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]){0}(?<thing>\g<number>-\g<number>|\g<number>){0}^(\g<thing>,)*\g<thing>$/
irb(main):006:0> s1.match(r)
=> #<MatchData "1-5,5,15-29" number:"29" thing:"15-29">
irb(main):007:0> s2.match(r)
=> #<MatchData "1,28,1-31,15" number:"15" thing:"15">
irb(main):008:0> s3.match(r)
=> #<MatchData "15,25,3" number:"3" thing:"3">
irb(main):009:0> s4.match(r)
=> #<MatchData "1-24,5-6,2-9" number:"9" thing:"2-9">
irb(main):010:0> '1-1-1-1'.match(r)
=> nil
```

Comment: `(?<number>[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])`should probably be written `(?<number>3[01]|[12]\d|[1-9])`

Answer (score 0):

An optimal Regex for this topic could be:

```
^(?'int'[1-2]?[1-9]|3[01])((,\g'int')|(-\g'int'(?=$|,)))*$
```

### [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sR7sE7)