# Java regular expression to validate numeric comma separated number and hyphen

Tags: java, regex

```
Valid1: 2

valid2: 3-5

Valid3: 2,4-6

valid4: 2,4,5

valid5: 2-7,8-9

Valid4: 2,5-7,9-13,15,17-20
```

All the expression on the above should be valid in one regex.
the digit in the left side of hyphen should be smaller than right hand side.

Comment: What have you tried so far? No one is going to give you a full answer unless you show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Regular expressions have no concept of the size of a number. You will need more than a regex to solve this problem.

Comment: for regexp you will need to use the following symbols : + , ( ) \d - you will also need to validate the numbers themselves though because you cannot compare numbers with regexp

Comment: i would recommend making your own finite state machine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to build a regular expression to check pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599725/trying-to-build-a-regular-expression-to-check-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as @MikeFHay suggested above, regex were not made to check if one digit is bigger than the other (for that you'll have to parse the expression). If we'll ignore that requirement - the rest can be achieved via the following regex:

```
((\d\,(?=\d))|(\d\-(?=\d))|\d)+
```

in Java:

```
"((\\d\\,(?=\\d))|(\\d\\-(?=\\d))|\\d)+"
```

Explanation:
This regex uses lookahead to validate that each comma or dash is preceded and followed by a digit: `(\d\,(?=\d))` so that each "substring" that contains a dash/comma will have to be in the format of: digit,digit or digit-digit.

Of course that a number that doesn't contain commas/dashes is also valid - hence the rightmost side of the `or` which is simply a `\d`

Link to **[online demo](http://regexr.com?36uli)**